# Can Java paint() call just once?

Tags: java, paint

If I include the println code and launch in Eclipse, Java console mostly prints three "x". Sometimes prints two "x". Why does it not print just one "x"?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    setBackground(background);
    System.out.println("x");

    // graphic etc.
}
```

Comment: It's safer to assume that paint() **will* run far more often than you call it.

Answer (score 3):

Many things can trigger a call to paint, including your code, by calling `repaint()`, the JVM by rendering the GUI, and the operating system by telling the JVM that "dirty" regions need to be painted, and understand that this is something that you do not have control over. For this reason (and for others), program logic should remain out of all painting methods. If you need help doing this, then by all means post more pertinent code.

For more on this, please read: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

As a side recommendation please note that if yours is a Swing application, the  paint method should rarely be overridden, and instead you should override the `paintComponent` method of a JPanel or JComponent.

Side rec 2: never call `setBackground(...)` from within a painting method. This will trigger an unnecessary repaint, and is one reason why you're seeing three "x's" being printed. Instead, call this once, probably from your class's constructor.